# Chamar método PHP com ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho um código que faz uma validação em javascript, e gostaria que se validado como verdadeiro, alterasse uma tabela do banco de dados. Pensei em usar ajax, para assim que validar como verdadeiro, chamar um método num arquivo.php, porém não sei como faze-lo.

Seria necessário enviar uma session para o ajax `$_SESSION['membro'];` e o ajax com essa session, alterasse na database onde o nome do membro seja igual ao da session.
Seria algo do tipo assim?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php', //caminho do arquivo a ser executado
    dataType: 'html', //tipo do retorno
    type: 'post', //metodo de envio
    data: session:$_SESSION['membro'], //valores enviados ao script
});
```

Comment: A pergunta é sobre esse trecho de JavaScript, ou sobre a parte do PHP?

Comment: Sobre o ajax. O método para alterar a tabela eu sei, não sei como chamar ele enviando esta `SESSION`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código é quase esse, mas o parâmetro `data` deve conter um objeto (enquanto no seu código tem um erro de sintaxe, hehe):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php', //caminho do arquivo a ser executado
    dataType: 'html', //tipo do retorno
    type: 'post', //metodo de envio
    data: { session: '<?php echo $_SESSION['membro'] ?>' } //valores enviados ao script
       // ^     ------ faltavam as chaves acima -------  ^ 
});
```

No PHP, o valor passado estará em `$_POST["session"]` (sendo "session" o nome da chave onde você colocou o valor no JS.

O código acima assume que o PHP pode executar no contexto desse JavaScript, e pegar o session. Se não funcionar, tente engessar o session assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php', //caminho do arquivo a ser executado
    dataType: 'html', //tipo do retorno
    type: 'post', //metodo de envio
    data: { session: 100 } //valores enviados ao script
});
```

Comment: Será isso uma boa prática ?

Comment: Na parte do script, eu manipulo este valor enviado na parte da data como? `$variavel = session;` ?

Comment: @Edilson O que exatamente?

Comment: @Guilherme Evite misturar PHP com JS. Você não tem o código do usuário em algum lugar da página sem ser no PHP? Por exemplo, na URL?

Comment: Não só tenho no PHP mesmo... Eu sei que é uma ganbiarra nojenta misturar as duas linguagens, porém eu necessito que se a validação em JS retorne true, execute uma mudança no banco de dados SQL, e a não ser que eu possa manipular o banco através do JS não vejo outra opção :O

Comment: @Guilherme Use o PHP para salvar o código do usuário em um campo hidden (`echo '<input type="hidden" id="usr" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["membro"]?>">`). No JS você pode pegar o valor desse campo para passar de volta para o servidor.

Comment: Como eu faço o envio desse input pela parte `data` do JS? Ficaria algo do tipo isso `data: { session: usr }` ? E como eu faria para tratar essa variável dentro do PHP?

Comment: @Guilherme `data: { session: $('#usr').val() }`

Comment: E eu posso tratar ela assim no PHP? `$variavel = $_POST['usr'];`

Comment: Não, ela vai chegar como `$_POST['session']`, e não `$_POST['usr']`. O nome da **chave** que você usar no `data` do JS será a chave no PHP também. @Guilherme

Comment: Cara, entendi perfeitamente e creio eu que tenha editad o código corretamente, porém não está executando o SQL. Editei o post principal com o JS e PHP prontos, tem como tu dar uma olhada por cima para ver se acha algo de errado? Porque não sei se o erro está no JS que não está chamando o script ou no PHP em si

Comment: @Guilherme É melhor postar uma pergunta separada sobre isso, em vez de editar essa (aqui no site fazemos assim pois aumenta a chance de cada pergunta ajudar outras pessoas, e não só quem perguntou).

Comment: Ok! Vou abrir agora mesmo. Muito obrigado xD